# ZendFramework - How do i declare static global constant, to have this available in my all controllers and models?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have 50 controllers, and 90 Models. Everywhere i was using/repeating same words 'login' and 'success'. I want to make one global constant so that i can access from anywhere in my controllers and models. How or where do you declare this following 2 line.

Try to put this somewhere to have global access:

```
defined('MYFIXED_WORD_SUCCESS')
    || define('MYFIXED_WORD_SUCCESS', "success");
defined('MYFIXED_WORD_LOGIN')
    || define('MYFIXED_WORD_SUCCESS', "login");
```

Example of repeating:

```
if (count($result) > 0) 
{
  $return = array(
        'flag'  => 'login',  // replace it with MYFIXED_WORD_
        'result'=> 'success',// replace it with MYFIXED_WORD_
        'extra' => array(group'=>$rec->group,));
```

Comment: the bootstrap would be a good place or the index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you include or set in bootstrap.php should be available from anywhere in your application. But have a look at [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) since it does pretty much what you want but in a organised way.
Alternatively you could set it in application.ini and get to it thru [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.config.html).

You "could" put it in /public/index.php but in my opinion its not the place to put such thing. Imagine when you have thousands of const like that how it would polute a file that basically never should change.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your variables in [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a `constants.ini` file in `application/configs` folder, and, in Bootstrap.php, I'm iterating and defining constants:

```
/**
 * Loads app-wide constants from ini file
 */
protected function _initDefineConstants()
{
    $constantFile = APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/constants.ini';
    $iniParser = new Zend_Config_Ini($constantFile);

    foreach ($iniParser->toArray() as $constName => $constantVal) {
        define($constName, $constantVal);
    }
}
```

Example of `constants.ini`:

```
ADMIN_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 20
PRODUCT_VIEW_REC = 4 ; number of recommended products in Product view

; columns in "options" table
OPT_COL_VAT = vat
OPT_TEL_ORDER = telephone_order
OPT_QUICK_EMAIL = quick_order_email
```

Comment: How do you access these defined constant in a layout for exemple ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you mean by "layout", but if it's something wrapped in `<?php ?>`, they're available. They're constants after all (global namespace).